# Draw TrueType small caps text using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow to draw text on an image:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

im = Image.new("L", (400, 50), color="black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Roboto-Medium.ttf", 28)
draw.text((0, 0), "How To Get Small Caps?", font=font, fill="white")
im.save('small_caps.png')
```

But I cannot figure out how to draw that string in small caps instead of regular characters.

Comment: If you don't have a small caps version of the font, which would be ideal, it seems like you could simply change all the letters to uppercase and use a slightly smaller font size to draw them — there's nothing built-in that does that AFAIK.

Comment: Note that if doing what I suggested in my previous comment, each letter will need to be processed individually. You can figure-out where to place the next character using Pillow's [`ImageFont.getsize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize) method to see how much space each one takes up.

Comment: Jonathan, FYI: I have created [this image](https://imgur.com/cq5F651) using an OpenType parser I have been working on for the past – well, *month*  Through it, you can use common OT features such as `smcp` and the much-missed `kern`, as well as swash, ligature, oldstyle numbering, capital spacing, and lots more. I still have to streamline it but will update my answer if I have anything on Github.

Comment: @usr2564301 This would be useful. I managed to get what I needed from your snippet (and http://mathew-kurian.github.io/CharacterMap/ to examine glyphs). However, a Python library to parse this is surprisingly missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Roboto-Medium *does* contain actually drawn-to-size small capitals, but they are not mapped to a Unicode codepoint. That means that the regular way of specifying characters in a simple string is not going to work.

OpenType-aware software can access the glyphs through the OpenType feature `c2sc` (which substitutes capital letters with their small caps equivalent) and `smcp` (which does the same, but for lowercase letters only). These translation tables reside inside the font in the TrueType `GSUB` table – which are encoded in a particularly *devious* format. That's probably why the PIL programmers never bothered to implement it (and other potentially useful OpenType features such as super- and subscripting, kerning, and localized letter forms per language).

The Python module `freetype` *can* get access to the raw glyphs. But, likewise, the FreeType developers briefly considered adding OpenType feature parsing to their library but decided against it and have FreeType focus only on *drawing*. Nevertheless, you can still use `freetype` to fetch and rasterize *any* glyph in all fonts. The only thing is, you are going to hard-code the glyph indexes.

"Glyph indexes" are nothing more than 'what encoding value corresponds to which image', starting at 0 and continuing up to the last glyph. The possible encodings for a font reside elsewhere in the font data; it may contain decidated Windows encodings (the ol' "code pages" thing – but larger), full Unicode encodings, MacRoman, and a smattering of others. You only have to select an encoding and tell what character code *in that encoding* you want, `freetype` will look up the correct glyph for you.

But OpenType features can overrule this. It's a separate set of translations, driven by what feature you select (and which script, and even for what *language*). A fully OpenType aware interface will see your glyphs, raise the stakes with the required features, and return a raw *glyph index*.

Since there may be lots of raw glyphs in a single font file, not every encoding will point to every *glyph* in the font. Imagine poor old MacRoman, for example, with only 256 possible characters. No way you can address all of Roboto's 1294 glyphs with that. Even Unicode, with its thousands and thousands of defined entries, cannot address them all, because it is possible to create *stylistic alternatives* for some characters (such as swash capitals) which, as far as Unicode is concerned, are identical to their original, and combinations of characters to use as *ligatures*, where a complete sequence such as `Zapfino` is drawn as a single complicated glyph (that one's in the font "Zapfino"; and it is awesome).

Some font designers allow access to special characters through 'private' Unicode codepoints (meaning "free for everyone to define") but I don't think Roboto has this.

It is possible to ask FreeType for the complete `GSUB` table and then parse this to find the proper translations for small caps, and if you do so you'll be happy to find that your code will then work with *any* font with real small caps (!), but it is a stupendous amount of work.

So I cheated. Some software allows per-glyph inspection of fonts, and I used Adobe InDesign to look up the glyph index for all of `A..Z` in small caps.

This does have a drawback, though. It will *only* work (reliably) with one particular release of Roboto-Medium, because the designer can add, delete, and generally move glyphs around at will for each new release. Remember that this does not have any influence on how other software handles the font! The encoding and OpenType tables are adjusted to match, so the software doesn't *need* to know anything about each font's glyph indexes.
There is also no guarantee **at all** that these same indexes will work with the other fonts in the Roboto family. The designer may have used the exact same layout and may have not. Practically, as per above, they should not even have to care about it.

I have downloaded the latest, Version 2.137; 2017; if you don't have that one, download it first!

Below is some sample code to print out grayscale values for all small caps glyphs, in order, with their horizontal offset from the glyph's starting point (left offset) and vertical height in pixels, measured from the baseline. Adjust at will to match PIL's own text drawing routines; it may take some finicking to get it Just Right™.

(Apologies for the rather basic code sample. I managed to muck up my PIL installation for both Python 2.7 and 3.(something) and so I cannot show something graphically; fortunately, the `freetype` module still worked.)

```
import freetype
import os.path

smcapGlyphs = [563,562,561,560,552,486,485,484,483,482,481,480,479,
 478,477,476,475,474,473,472,471,470,469,468,467,466]

def dump_bytes(buf,wide,high):
    for y in range(high):
        for x in range(wide):
            print ('%02x ' % buf[y*wide+x], end='')
        print ()

face = freetype.Face(os.path.expanduser('~')+"/Library/Fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf")
face.set_char_size( 48*64 )

for index,i in enumerate(smcapGlyphs):
    face.load_glyph(i)

    print (chr(65+index))
    bitmap = face.glyph.bitmap
    width  = face.glyph.bitmap.width
    rows   = face.glyph.bitmap.rows
    pitch = face.glyph.bitmap.pitch
    print (face.glyph.bitmap_left)
    print (face.glyph.bitmap_top)

    dump_bytes (bitmap.buffer, pitch,rows)
    print ()
```